# Prime number checking function not working for negative numbers

Tags: python, primes

```
def is_prime(x):
    x = abs(x)
    if x == 0 or x == 1:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x%i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

The tester says the above code shouldn't return true for x = -7.
Please help.
Thank you :)

**Edit: **

im so sorry, just read somewhere that any number less than 2 (i.e 0, 1 and all negative numbers are not prime

Comment: because your for loop is from range 2 to the x so for -7 it won't execute anything. Please improve your logic for prime numbers

Comment: What do you mean? `is_prime(-7)` does return `True`.

Comment: Muhammad you forgot the second line of the program. Please improve your code-reading.

Comment: It does return true for `is_prime(-7)`. What is your doubt ?

Comment: In traditional mathematics, negative numbers are not considered prime, if you remove the `abs()` call and set your first guard to `if x < 2: return False` it would cover it.

Comment: @AChampion thank you, now i got it. I Just read somewhere that any number less than 2 (i.e 0, 1 and all negative numbers are not prime

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002459/do-we-have-negative-prime-numbers  is a somewhat more rigorous outline of the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It does return True for me. Check the value of x after you call abs(x), it will maybe help.

Comment: im so sorry, just read somewhere that any number less than 2 (i.e 0, 1 and all negative numbers are **not prime**)

Answer (score 0):

It does return True for negative numbers for me.

Also you can run the loop from 2 to x/2 and reduce the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

My Python is not good, but something like this should work better:

```
def is_prime(x):
    # Handle 1, 0 and negatives.
    if x < 2:
        return False
    # Handle even numbers.
    elif x % 2 == 0:
        return x == 2
    # Test with odd divisors.
    for i in range(3, sqrt(x), 2):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

The `sqrt(x)` limit is a big time saver, and dealing with even numbers separately can halve the time with well mixed inputs.